# CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND when trying to build library (MinGW)

Tags: cmake, mingw

I am using VS Code, CMake Tools, Ninja and MinGW as my compiler.

When trying to build a static library, the command line output reads:

```
[build] cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E rm -f libTest.a && CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND qc libTest.a  CMakeFiles/Test.dir/Test.cpp.obj && cd ."
[build] 'CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I'm assuming that the ar.exe library archiver could not be found, however I can compiler a normal program just fine, and there is indeed an ar.exe executable in the same location as g++.exe (the bin folder).

Why can't Cmake/Ninja locate the archiver?

Comment: It looks like CMake's compiler identification did not go well, or something got changed since the initial identification of the MinGW compiler. Did you try a fresh CMake configuration (i.e. deleting the CMake cache and/or build folder and re-building)? FWIW, you can manually specify the ar.exe location by passing it as a CMake command line argument, e.g.: `-DCMAKE_AR=C:/MinGW/bin/ar.exe`

Answer (score 0):

`&&` in between commands means the second command will be executed if the first completed without error (`%ERRORLEVEL%` = 0)

The first line contains `&& CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND` which means `CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND` is to be run as a command (with the parameters following it).

The error you're getting says this command or executable file does not exist.

It looks like CMake set this value for the `ar` tool path as it couldn't find it.

When CMake is used to configure the project you must make sure `ar.exe` can be found in the `PATH`.

It should be included with MinGW.

For a recent standalone build of MinGW-w64 (both for win32 and win64) see: http://winlibs.com/